# How To Fix Evernote findNotesMetadata() Returning { "errorCode": 3, "parameter": "authenticationToken" } In NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, evernote, evernote-app-notebook

Using evernote's JS-SDK I've been successful in authenticating and authorizing third party client and fetching their notebooks, But when trying to search note using search queries i kept getting  `{ "errorCode": 3,   "parameter": "authenticationToken" }` even though oauthAccessToken is present in user session. I have tried passing in the accessToken directly as parameter to findNotesMetadata() but that gives me **"Incorrect number of arguments passed to findNotesMetadata: Expected 4 but found 5"**

I'd seen the same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171200/evernote-api-errorcode-3-parameter-authenticationtoken) 2 years ago but didn't get any answer, Any form of help is welcome. Below is my current code

```
exports.searchNote = async (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.oauthAccessToken) {
    console.log(SESSION =>", req.session);

    const token = req.session.oauthAccessToken;
    const searchParam = req.query.search;
    console.log("ACCESS_TOKEN =>", token);
    console.log("SEARCH_WORD =>", searchParam);
    const client = new Evernote.Client({
      consumerKey: config.API_CONSUMER_KEY,
      consumerSecret: config.API_CONSUMER_SECRET,
      token: token,
      sandbox: config.SANDBOX,
      china: config.CHINA,
    });
    const noteStore = client.getNoteStore();    
    const filter = new Evernote.NoteStore.NoteFilter({
      words: searchParam === undefined ? "" : searchParam,
      ascending: true,
    });
    const spec = new Evernote.NoteStore.NotesMetadataResultSpec({
      includeTitle: true,
      includeContentLength: true,
      includeCreated: true,
      includeUpdated: true,
      includeDeleted: true,
      includeUpdateSequenceNum: true,
      includeNotebookGuid: true,
      includeTagGuids: true,
      includeAttributes: true,
      includeLargestResourceMime: true,
      includeLargestResourceSize: true,
    });

    noteStore
      .findNotesMetadata(filter, 0, 500, spec)
      .then((notesMetadataList) => {
        // data.notes is the list of matching notes
        console.log(notesMetadataList);
        res.json({ NotesMetaData: notesMetadataList });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Search_Error =>", err);
        res.status(500).json({ Search_Error: err });
      });
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({
      session: req.session,
      msg: "You do not have an active session, login and authorize NoteTaker to access your Evernote Account",
    });
  }
};
```